# Assign a new array to a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm looking for the best way to go through an array and assign a second array and loop it. Below is a basic outline of the array I want to use.

```
$firstarray = array('one','two','three','four', 'five', 'six');
$secondarray = array('blue', 'green', 'pink');
```

I would like it to print out

```
one = blue
two = green
three = pink
four = blue
```

and so on..

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. New to php and stackexchange.

Comment: you mean you want to create a new array or create new variables `$one`, `$two`, ...?

Comment: So you just want to print the results, or do you want a new array with the 2 arrays combined with one as the key and the other as the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$firstarray  = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
$secondarray = array('blue', 'green', 'pink');

foreach($firstarray as $index => $value)
  echo $value . ' = ' . $secondarray[$index % count($secondarray)] . PHP_EOL;
```

Use index of elements of `$firstarray` as counter, take modulo from it by the number of the elements in `$secondarray` (loop through the second array) and output the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a multi-dimension array. We can't see how you are building the array, so it's hard to give you much help without more code. The array would look something like this:

```
$multi_array = array ( 
    array("number"=>"one","color"=>"blue"), 
    array("number"=>"two","color"=>"green")
)
```

Then you could print it like this:

```
foreach($multi_array as $array){
     echo $array["number"]." = ".$array["color"];
}
```